# Empty singular submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I search for a module $M$ with its singular submodule $Z(M)$  the empty set, i.e. for every element $m$ of $M$ the annihilator of $m$ in $R$ is not essential, say, as right $R$-module; or proving that such a module does not exist!

Of course, I know that the product  $Z(M). soc(R_R)$ is always zero, where $soc(R_R)$ is the socle of $R_R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annihilator of $0\in M$ is $R$, which is always going to be essential. The singular submodule always has at least that.